# LaunchUriAsync with custom scheme when windows 8 metro app start

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, uri

I try to LaunchUriAsync when my app start with this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Navigate to the given URI in a web browser task if the uri is valid
/// We can use all scheme provide by windows excepted file:///
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">Uri of the page</param>
public async void TryNavigateToBrowser(string uri)
{
  if (uri != null && uri != "")
  {
    try
    {
      /* Firstly we try to made a launch async for custom URI scheme */
      var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri));

      /* Secondly if it doesn't works we try the same but in UI thread
       * If a custom scheme is tried to be displayed in UI thread UI should crash */
      if (!success)
      {
        CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,
        () =>
        {
          /* we made a synchronous call to LaunchUriAsync in UI thread */
          var successUI = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(uri)).AsTask().Result;

          if (!successUI)
          {
            TryNavigateToBrowser(uri);
          }
        });
      }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      /* If URI isn't well formated we try to found a file to launch it */
      NavigateToLocalUri(uri);
    }
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// Use to provide customer sended URI for opening file in app storage
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri"></param>
internal static async void NavigateToLocalUri(string uri)
{
  try
  {
    StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(uri);
    if (storageFile != null)
    {
      var success = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(storageFile);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception)
  {
    /* If no file can be displayed we send a capptain error */
    throw new CapptainException("URI cannot be opened ");
  }
}
```

I try to use this in App.xaml.cs "OnLaunched" method.

This works for a lot of URI but by attaching to http://tozon.info/blog/post/2011/10/06/Windows-8-Metro-declarations-Protocol.aspx I can't use it for URI with custom scheme when app start. That froze UI. But when app is already started and I set this function to a button this work for custom scheme. 
I don't know why this doesn't work on app start

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older post and you might have figured it out, but I think I have an answer. I've run into something like this before.

If your OnActivate and OnProtocolActivate methods are exactly the same as what's seen in that post, then it will not work if the app is not already running. This is because your app doesn't have a frame to work with. If there's no frame, then there's nothing to do any programmatic work to set up the view you want to load. If the app was already running, then there was already a frame to do work for you, which is why it worked if it was already started.

Look at the OnLaunched code that comes with a new project. They create a new frame if it doesn't exist. I believe if you simply add the following code at the start of your OnProtocolActivated method, it should then work if the app is not yet started.

```
private void OnProtocolActivated(ProtocolActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

    if (rootFrame == null)
    {                
        rootFrame = new Frame();
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }
/// Your code goes after
```

Hope that helps.